# C++ two types dependent of each other

Tags: c++, types

I would like to have two types:

1. Unordered_map that maps type K to the pair of type V and iterator to an element of the second type
2. List of iterators to the map's elements

Something like this:

```
using mapType = std::unordered_map<K, std::pair<V, typename orderType>>;
using orderType = std::list<typename mapType::iterator>;
```

This doesn't work, because orderType is not defined in the first line. And even if it would be somehow, this would lead to infinite type recursion.

How can i declare those types? Is there a way to somehow use list iterators without implicit list type?

EDIT: I don't want to store any additional copies of type K, they are big.

Comment: In your case you could just store the keys (`K`) instead of the iterators. Same result, if maybe a bit slower. If you show or explain how and why you need this, someone might find a better solution.

Comment: Note that iterators are invalidated if `unordered_map` is rehashed.

Comment: Is this a graph? Maybe it would make more sense to split it into an adjacency list and a separate map of K* to vertex index.

Answer (score 0):

Since a map iterator only needs a forward reference to the value type, you can use an intermediate type to break up the cycle:

```cpp
struct orderType : std::list<std::map<K, std::pair<V, orderType>>::iterator> {
    using std::list<std::map<K, std::pair<V, orderType>>::iterator>::list;
};
using mapType = std::map<K, std::pair<V, orderType>>;
```

usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    K k1 = GetK1();
    K k2 = GetK2();
    V v = GetV();

    mapType m;
    m.insert({ k1, { v, orderType{} }});
    m.insert({ k2, { v, orderType{} }});
    m[k1].second.push_back(m.find(k2));
    m[k2].second.push_back(m.find(k1));
}
```

PoC demo: https://godbolt.org/